# Extract data from multiple .xml files in multiple folders

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I am not sure what I am doing here. I am trying to extract data from XML files that have the same names but are stored in different folders. There are no errors when running it, but I get no return data or nothing printed. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

```
import glob
import os
from lxml import etree

dir = 'C:/Users/franc/AppData/Local/Temp/LSTO/'
for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, 'summary.xml')):
   with open(file) as f:
      data = etree.parse(f)
      root = data.root()
      for temp in root.iter('Summary'):
         print(temp.attrib)
         temp_data = '/summary/@maxTemperature'

         print(temp_data)
```

I am trying to extract maxTemperature data from this XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Summary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <misc partMass="4.8589068478323991" name="LSTO, Boron Nitride + 1 other"/>
    <summary maxTemperature="150.679214" minTemperature="20" multiMode="Discrete" volume="1531.5476989044932" firstMaterialFraction="0.4078046203055925" countMaterials="2" maxElementStress="-3.40282347E+38" minElementStress="3.40282347E+38" maxStress="-3.40282347E+38" minStress="3.40282347E+38" maxDisplacementLength="0">
        <minDisplacement z="3.40282347E+38" y="3.40282347E+38" x="3.40282347E+38"/>
        <maxDisplacement z="-3.40282347E+38" y="-3.40282347E+38" x="-3.40282347E+38"/>
        <cauchyStressMin>
            <normal z="3.40282347E+38" y="3.40282347E+38" x="3.40282347E+38"/>
            <shear z="3.40282347E+38" y="3.40282347E+38" x="3.40282347E+38"/>
        </cauchyStressMin>
        <cauchyStressMax>
            <normal z="-3.40282347E+38" y="-3.40282347E+38" x="-3.40282347E+38"/>
            <shear z="-3.40282347E+38" y="-3.40282347E+38" x="-3.40282347E+38"/>
        </cauchyStressMax>
    </summary>
    <materials>
        <material name="Boron Nitride" density="2" id="1">
            <matrix density="2" CTE="0" Gzp="24550" nuz="0.23999999463558197" Ez="27000" nu="0.23999999463558197" Ep="94500"/>
            <properties>
                <textProperty value="Yes" key="Soluble Support Available?"/>
                <numericProperty value="4.5" key="Elongation at Break" costType="Unknown" unit="%"/>
                <numericProperty value="124" key="Ultimate Tensile Strength" costType="Unknown" unit="MPa"/>
                <numericProperty value="20" key="Infill Density" costType="Unknown" unit="%"/>
                <textProperty value="Triangles" key="Infill Pattern"/>
                <numericArrayProperty key="Thermal Matrix" unit="W/(mmC)">0.45 0 0 0 0.45 0 0 0 0.03</numericArrayProperty>
                <textProperty value="Boron Nitride" key="Material Name"/>
                <textProperty value="Metal" key="General Material Type"/>
                <textProperty value="PLA" key="Specific Material Type"/>
            </properties>
        </material>
        <material name="Alumina" density="3.98" id="2">
            <matrix density="3.9800000190734863" CTE="0" Gzp="126500" nuz="0.27000001072883606" Ez="314000" nu="0.27000001072883606" Ep="314000"/>
            <properties>
                <textProperty value="Yes" key="Soluble Support Available?"/>
                <numericProperty value="4.5" key="Elongation at Break" costType="Unknown" unit="%"/>
                <numericProperty value="124" key="Ultimate Tensile Strength" costType="Unknown" unit="MPa"/>
                <numericProperty value="80" key="Infill Density" costType="Unknown" unit="%"/>
                <textProperty value="Triangles" key="Infill Pattern"/>
                <numericArrayProperty key="Thermal Matrix" unit="W/(mmC)">0.02525 0 0 0 0.02525 0 0 0 0.02525</numericArrayProperty>
                <textProperty value="Alumina" key="Material Name"/>
                <textProperty value="Ceramic" key="General Material Type"/>
                <textProperty value="PLA" key="Specific Material Type"/>
            </properties>
        </material>
    </materials>
</Summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over `Summary` elements, but the element you want is `summary` (notice the difference in case?).

You also don't need to open the xml file before parsing.

I'm also not sure what the `temp_data` string is supposed to be doing.

You're also not iterating over multiple folders; you're processing a single file in a single directory. How do you intend on supplying the directories? A list of directories?

Here's an example that will at least get you pulling `@maxTemperature` from a single XML file...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("summary.xml")

for summary in tree.iter("summary"):
    print(summary.get("maxTemperature", "Max temperature not found."))
```